# Ember: How to reach a HTML element that has an action handler?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How could I get the currently clicked HTML element in an ember action?

```
<button {{action 'open'}}></button>

actions: {
  open: function() {
    // How to get the clicked button.
  }
}
```

I tried passing an event and catching it with $(e.eventTarget) but `e` is undefined.

Comment: Why do you ask questions if you dont respond to the answer?

Comment: Wait, i don't test your answer yet, i will in the next 3 days, and if it works i'm going to check as correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty odd request by you. One way you could achieve this is by marking the button with an id and sending it with action.

```
<button {{action 'open' 'myButton'}} id="myButton"></button>

actions: {
  open: function(buttonId) {
    var clickedBtn = this.$('#' + buttonId);
  }
}
```

More dynamically

```
{{#each array as |item|}}

  <button {{action 'open' item.id}} id={{item.id}}></button>

{{/each}}
```